# Stuck at ACPI BIOS error Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: boot, grub2

> Sudden issue after rebooting Ubuntu, after selecting Ubuntu from the grub menu I am stuck inside the kernel and it constantly says Mt device/ not supplied.

Comment: Try to boot with a previous kernel using grub.

Comment: Can you elaborate ? I am dual booting with windows and I have no clue how to